# Binomial Identity with strange coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

In my work, I have come across the following equation

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^m \sum_{l = 0}^{n-m} {m \choose k} {n - m \choose l} (-1)^k r_{k + l} $$

where $r_n = 1$ if $n$ is congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4, and $r_n = -1$ if $n$ is congruent to 2 or 3 modulo 4. I've seen some identities involving the products ${m \choose k} {n - m \choose l}$, but I can't seem to find an algebraic trick to reduce this form to a standard identity. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is

$$\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k} (-1)^k
\sum_{l=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose l} r_{k+l}.$$

We have that

$$r_{k+l} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{k+l+1}} (1+w - w^2-w^3 + \cdots)
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{k+l+1}} 
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\; dw.$$

We get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w}
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{w^k}
\sum_{l=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose l} \frac{1}{w^l}
\; dw
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w}
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{w^k}
\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)^{n-m}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-m}}{w^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{w^k}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-m}}{w^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\left(1-\frac{1}{w}\right)^m
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-m} (w-1)^m}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1+w - w^2-w^3}{1-w^4}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-m} (w-1)^m}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1+w}{1+w^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-m+1} (w-1)^m}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+w^2}
\; dw.$$

Now  checking on  the residue  at infinity  by a  circular contour  of
radius   $R$   we   obtain   a   term  of   order   $2\pi   R   \times
R^{n+1}/R^{n+1}/R^2$ which is $2\pi/R$ and vanishes so that residue is
zero. This  leaves for the  sum the residues at  $w=\pm i$ and  we get
(remember to flip the sign at the end)

$$\exp(-(n+1)\pi i/2)
\sqrt{2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2i} \exp(+(n-m+1)\pi i/4)\exp(+3m\pi i/4) \\
- \exp(+(n+1)\pi i/2) 
\sqrt{2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2i} \exp(-(n-m+1)\pi i/4)\exp(-3m\pi i/4)
\\ = \sqrt{2}^{n+1} \sin(-(2n+2)\pi/4 +(n-m+1)\pi/4 + 3m\pi/4).$$

This yields $$- \sqrt{2}^{n+1} \sin((2m-n-1)\pi/4)$$ or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sqrt{2}^{n+1} \sin((n+1-2m)\pi/4).}$$

Comment: I don't completely understand how you get the integral formula for $r_n$. Is this a general technique?

Comment: Alternatively we may use formal power series notation if you find it easier to process. We obtain $$r_{k,l} = [w^{k+l}] (1+w-w^2-w^3+\cdots)$$ which is seen to hold by inspection. We sum the geometric series to get the formula. Also, there are several users that solve these types of sums on MSE and you may yet see a completely different approach.

Comment: I see what you mean now - you're using Cauchy's integral formula with a generating function - clever :)

Comment: This is the so-called Egorychev method which has been in use in various guises for decades by many mathematicians, not always being identified by that name.

Comment: Nice uniform cascade of integrals. :)